# Centralise log mechanism

Tags: c#, design-patterns, logging, nlog

I have big enterprise solution containing many different project (class ,mvc , wpf ) I want to write a mechanism to log my exceptions or selected information from any of them and write to txt. I read about nlog, but am asking about the best practice to do that.

Comment: After more than 250 questions I'm sure you've read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) more than once. Do it again.

Comment: @CodeCaster all I need how to make a centralized project or mechanism to collect the errors without repeating code

Comment: That's nice. Do you have a specific question that's not too broad?

Comment: what's the best practice to do that using webservice for that or what

Answer (score 0):

I prefer AOP like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) for logging and error handling.

(but yes, CodeCaster is right. Be more accurate!)